# Twitter website gives a different response when sending a request using python-requests

Tags: python, https, python-requests, burp

When I send a get requests to `https://twitter.com/` using Burp Suite or CUrl, I get HTTP 302 with following body: `Found. Redirecting to /i/flow/login?redirect_after_login=%2F`. However, when I make the same get request from Python-requests, I get  HTTP 200, with a long html saying `Something went wrong, but don't fret, let's give it another shot.`. I cannot make requests to `https://twitter.com/`.

I used the following code with and without headers:

```
import requests

url = "https://twitter.com/"

headers = {
'Host' : 'twitter.com',
'Sec-Ch-Ua' : '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="104"',
'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile' : '?0',
'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform' : '"Windows"',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' : '1',
'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.102 Safari/537.36',
'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
'Sec-Fetch-Site' : 'none',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode' : 'navigate',
'Sec-Fetch-User' : '?1',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest' : 'document',
'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate',
'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
}

response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
```

It returns the same response regardless of the headers.

But with Burp Suite, using the same headers, or no headers, or with CUrl, with no headers, it returns the correct "HTTP 302" response.

Comment: The TLS fingerprint of Python is blacklisted at twitter (or the other way around: it is not white-listed thus not part of the allowed client systems).